# discord.py create a new command through a command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I want to create a command that can basically create another command through use, and then save it to a json file along with the guild id. Example: -add_command {command trigger} {content}. Is this possible, and if so how would I do it?

Comment: To do that, You will need to write some codes first, then you can come back here and ask for help on the problems that you face while you are coding it :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess this is what you mean...

Command used:
**-add_command Hey "Welcome! :D"**

Result:
**-Hey** -> Bot's answer would be <**Welcome! :D**>

If this is what you want to accomplish then...  (no full code sharing because you didn't upload any code yourself so I don't know if you understand these things and it is better that you learn rather than just copy).

The add_command part would look like...

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
# ^ Don't let random people create commands lol (unless you want them too...)
async def add_command(ctx, command_trigger, content):
    client.triggered_commands[message.guild.id][command_trigger] = content
    # ^ your client/bot can save your triggers globally for you :)
    # Do some json manipulation here to save the dict too.
    ctx.send("Command saved!") #Let the user know
```

For json manipulation see [this (example)](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python) and/or [this (documentation)](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html).

Then you can [listen to the messages](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message) that have [your bot's prefixes](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_prefix) and reply using the dict.

Note that JSON is not always the best choice to use to store data so you might want to dig into databases to keep your data safe.

You would also have to load your JSON data into your bot everytime the bot starts.

I'm kind of new into programming/discord.py so I'd also suggest that you join [discord.py official Discord server](https://discord.gg/r3sSKJJ) and ask for help there (: